# Batch file : how to rename a .xls file when another .xlsx file present in same folder?

Tags: excel, windows, batch-file, batch-rename

I have a folder with 1 batch file and 2 excel files - **old.xls** and **new.xlsx**.

I need to rename both these files to test.xls and test.xlsx by using the batch file in the same folder.

When I try to rename the .xlsx file I can successfully do it by using the following command:

```
ren *.xlsx test.xlsx
```

But when i try doing the same for the .xls file I get the following error :

```
ren *.xls test.xls

A duplicate file name exists, or the file
cannot be found.
```

Can someone tell me how to do this? I am new to batch files.

Comment: whats the directorys content after `ren *.xlsx test.xlsx` ? Why not use `old.xls` and `new.xlsx` instead of `ren *.xlsx` ?  My guess would be there is at least one other `.xls` file  beside `old.xls` in your directory so both get renamed to test.xls - the second one throws your error.

Comment: After ren *.xlsx test.xlsx only the new.xlsx file gets renamed to test.xlsx

The old.xls file stays as is.

Comment: I am using *.xlsx or *.xls because i want to be able to rename any .xlsx and .xls file to test.xlsx and test.xls

Comment: Well - you won''t be able to if there is more then 1  `whatever.xls` file in the directory - because the `ren` will try to rename both to the same filename, wich leads to the error you get

Comment: So how do i rename both the .xls and .xlsx file from the same batch file?

Comment: If there is more then one .xls file in the directory you can`t - NOT to the same test.xls name. You cant rename two files to the same name.

Comment: if there's only `old.xls` and `new.xlsx` then simply use `ren old.xls test.xls & ren new.xlsx test.xlsx`. `*.xls` will simply refer to [**all xls and xlsx files**](https://superuser.com/q/238900/241386) due to short names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
PUSHD "%sourcedir%"


ECHO directory before xlsx rename
DIR /x /a-d
REN *.xlsx test.xlsx
ECHO ============================
ECHO directory before XLS rename
DIR /x /a-d
ECHO.
FOR %%a IN (*.xls) DO ECHO "XLS" name found: %%a
ECHO.
FOR %%a IN (*.xls) DO IF /i "%%~xa"==".xls" REN "%%a" test.xls
ECHO ============================
ECHO directory after XLS rename
DIR /x /a-d


popd
GOTO :EOF
```

By default, every file or directory whose name does not comply with the DOS "8.3" filename convention (name of up to 8 characters, extension of up to 3, separated by a dot) will be assigned a "short name" that does comply.

The above code (I use `u:\sourcedir` as a test directory) will show the steps. Note that `dir /x` shows shortname and longname. `/a-d` suppresses directorynames).

so - the magic is to check that the fullname-extension actually *is* `.xls`.